# Xamarin database storage

Tags: database, xamarin

I'm new to programming an am looking to try to build something in Xamarin, a simple app. My question is storage - How do I store data? I understand that in computer applications we can use SQL Server, Oracle DB but how does it work in Xamarin?

Comment: Start with Xamarin's blog and recipes: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net , http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/ , https://blog.xamarin.com/modern-mobile-applications-with-couchbase-lite/ , ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use SQLite and SQLite async if you need to store local data.

If you want to control those data on server side, so you should use WebAPI.

Remember if you use sqllite the database will be located on Client side (user smart phone). And saved as a file. Extension is usually. Db3.